# A hash ("#") gets appended to my URL on load

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm working on a rather large legacy web app with the following stack: nginx, Django, React with React Router.

My problem is that any URL that I load gets a `#` appended to one before end if the last char is a `/`.

So `https://dev.local/feed/` becomes `https://dev.local/feed/#/`,

and `https://dev.local/create/?fid=user8:13/` becomes `https://dev.local/create/?fid=user8:13#/`.

I've investigated everything on the front end side. I'm using `browserRouter`, not `hashRouter`. I only have one router in my front end. I suspect this is coming from the back end, but not ruling out the front end. **Edit:** tried completely commenting out the router - the problem persists.

My question is how do I generally approach debug something like this? Browser debug tools - console, network, etc are not showing any redirects or URL rewrites. What would work here?

Comment: I agree, I don't think it's from the front end if you know for a fact you aren't appending `"#/"` anywhere. The `HashRouter` uses everything ***after*** the hash as the app route, i.e. something more like `"https://dev.local/#/feed"` or `"https://dev.local/#/create?fid=user8:13"` is what I'd expect with a hash router. Ah, and it looks like you've confirmed that on your end at the same time I was commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue disappeared after I ripped out a large node module with a lot of subdependancies (old version of `spectacle`). The list of subdependencies is quite extensive, and it's hard to pinpoint what solved the problem. Nothing obvious could be seen, like multiple version of `react-router` or `history` modules.